# When exporting FBX Animated Character, hand placement becomes wrong in some frames

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx, unreal-engine

I wanted to test an animation in Unity quickly, but I noticed, that the hand placement was wrong at the end of it. Then I reimported the FBX back into Blender, and the animation is still slightly corrupted. I've tried many different FBX export settings, but nothing worked, all transforms are 1,1,1 and everything seems fine.

I'm using Blender 4.0 and rig was made with Rigify.

Here is the video, The first half is from One instance of Blender with the original Animation, and the second is from the imported FBX:

https://streamable.com/nheh0d

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by a constraint that's not applied correctly. Try the following:

1. Hide all Bone Collections except *DEF*.

[image: Bone Collections]

2. Select all deform bones.
3. Run the Bake Action operator (can be found under Pose > Animation) with the following settings.

[image: Bake Action]

4. Export the animated character again, and test in Unity.
5. **Do not** save the blend file as the baking step will break the rig.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the answer. When I baked the bones the animation became broken again even without exporting. So, something was wrong during the baking step for sure.

Do you have any other guesses as to what can cause this issue?

Comment: Looks like this has something to do with the (Tweak) bones. Because, when I didn't use them, the animations looked fine.

Still, looks like a non-normal behavior, baking is supposed to bake animation one-to-one with precision, no matter what constraints are used and how.

Comment: @PlanetControl I am not exactly sure. The way I suggested to bake the animation is supposed to account for all constraints. There could be something else that's breaking the animation. I will have to dig around. If you can share the file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/), I may be able to figure it out.